# How to count rows using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

am creating an invoice system, in my product input I have table rows as below:

```html
<tr><td><input name="barcode[]" id="barcode" class="form-control"  onkeyup="showProduct(this.value ,this)"></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" id="description" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text"  name="serialnumber[]" id="serialnumber" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="number" name="s_price[]" id="s_price" class="form-control price"></td><td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total" class="form-control"></td><td><button class="btn btn-primary .addRows" id="removeRows" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td></tr>
```

and i have the appended table as:

```js
'<tr><td><input name="barcode[]" id="barcode'+count+'" class="form-control"  onkeyup="showProduct(this.value ,this)"></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" id="description'+count+'" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text"  name="serialnumber[]" id="serialnumber'+count+'" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity'+count+'" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="number" name="s_price[]" id="s_price'+count+'" class="form-control price"></td><td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total'+count+'" class="form-control"></td><td><button class="btn btn-danger .removeRows" id="removeRows" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button></td></tr>'
```

and here is my jquery:

```js
var max = 5;
        var x = 1; 
        $(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() {
        var count = $("tr").length;
  
    if (x <= max) {
        count++;
  var html = '<tr><td><input name="barcode[]" id="barcode'+count+'" class="form-control"  onkeyup="showProduct(this.value ,this)"></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" id="description'+count+'" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text"  name="serialnumber[]" id="serialnumber'+count+'" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity'+count+'" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="number" name="s_price[]" id="s_price'+count+'" class="form-control price"></td><td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total'+count+'" class="form-control"></td><td><button class="btn btn-danger .removeRows" id="removeRows" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button></td></tr>' 
  //added class remove and name..for inputs..
  
      $('#invoice-Item').append(html);
      x++;
    }
```

in other for me to get the content of each table I have this code:

```js
$("[id^=s_price]").each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                id = id.replace("s_price",'');
                var price = $('#s_price'+id).val();
                var quantity  = $('#quantity'+id).val();
```

all work fine when am about to create an invoice,
but when I want to update the invoice.  the count parameters only work with the first row and appended table. but it doesn't work with the foreach loop of tables rows fetch from database. please is there any idea of what I can do?

I want my table to be this way

```html
<tr><td><input type="text" id="name1"> </td> 
<td><input type="text" id="age1"> </td> 
<td><input type="number" id="phone1"> </td> </tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" id="name2"> </td> 
<td><input type="text" id="age2"> </td> 
<td><input type="number" id="phone2"> </td></tr>
```

. where the number at back of name will be generated from count++

please assist me if you can assist.

Comment: Where is the code that is supposed to update the invoice?

Comment: its same code as the creating invoice, i only wanted the count++ generated from javascript to work on my original html table.

Comment: I want each table row number to display along with td element